# Setup two (or more) routers in a single network as 1 big network

Tags: networking, router, dns, gateway

I'm sure this question was asked before in different shapes but even with my basic understanding of networking terms, I'm still struggling to solve this simple task..

So I have 2 routers in my home network, and I'm trying to configure them in such way that all devices will all be connected to each other.

[image]

I have a main router which is connected to the wall (the DSL / optical wall port)
there are few devices connected directly to the main router (for example PC1)
A secondary router is connected to the main router and has few child devices that are connected to the secondary router (for example PC2)

I'm trying to configure the routers such that PC1 will be able to ping PC2.

so my questions are:

1. for some reason the on the main router's devices list I see the secondary router with a given ip of 192.168.1.5. but in order to go into the secondary router's website I need to use PC2 and log into ip address 192.168.31.1 (this ip is configurable on secondary router's website) - **why are there 2 IP addresses and should I be worried about it somehow?**
2. **what DNS / gateway things I should do in order to make PC1 ping PC2?**

currently PC1 can ping 192.168.1.5 but not 192.168.31.1 and not 192.168.31.6. PC1 also can't access secondary router by going to 192.168.1.5

I've also manually set the PC1's subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 which only helped me to ping from PC2 to PC1 but not reversely

Comment: You should only allow a single router to handle DHCP.  This will allow a second and any other routers you might have to be extensions of that network. The reason you have to access the second machine on a separate subnet is due to the fact two routers cannot both handle DHCP on the same subnet.  I suppose you could have multiple devices like a router act as a DHCP server but it wouldn't work very well since they would be in conflict with one another constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS in the setup above should be provided by the ISP and is available by looking at the WAN port setup of the main router.

For your downstream routers you have likely connected the WAN port of the downstream device to your network. Hence new subnet.

For ONE big network:

Hook up a LAN port of a downstream device to your main network.

Give the downstream device a Static IP on your main network (192.168.1.x) so that it does not get lost in a restart.

Turn DHCP OFF on the downstream device. (Only ONE DHCP server in ONE big network).

Now it is part of your ONE big network.

Once you have ONE network, subnet mask should likely default to 255.255.255.0

Comment: If spending money isn't a concern, you can also pick up a cheap switch (**not** a router) and use it in place of the second router.

Comment: Nice explanation! apparently I had a mode in my (xiaomi) router for "router" which didn't allow me to set my ip address in the same subnet as the external ip (and also caused for the dual ip addresses), I switched it to relay mode which automatically disabled the DHCP as you described and now everything is working together in ONE big network. Yess! :))
THANK YOU!!

Comment: Thanks and you are most welcome.